# Invalid prop 'children' of type 'array' supplied to 'InfoWindow', expected a single ReactElement

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

```
  render() {
    const { showingInfoWindow, activePosition, selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={8}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 89, lng: -53 }}
      >
        {this.displayMarkers()}

        {showingInfoWindow ? (<InfoWindow position={this.state.activePosition} visible={this.state.showingInfowindow} onClose={this.onClose}>
          <div>
            <bold>Title: </bold>
            {this.state.selected.title}
          </div>
          <div>
            <bold>Description: </bold>
            {this.state.selected.description}
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>) : null}
      </Map>
    );
  }
```

I checked other answers and it seems this error message means I am providing more than one child react element to InfoWindow, but I don't see how I am doing that. It'd make sense if the error message were directed to Map with all the Marker children elements, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what that error/warning message means.

[InfoWindow](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/src/components/InfoWindow.js#L106-L116)

```
InfoWindow.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired, // <-- allows single child only
  map: PropTypes.object,
  marker: PropTypes.object,
  position: PropTypes.object,
  visible: PropTypes.bool,

  // callbacks
  onClose: PropTypes.func,
  onOpen: PropTypes.func
}
```

You can wrap them in a div or Fragment

```
{showingInfoWindow ? (
  <InfoWindow position={this.state.activePosition} visible={this.state.showingInfowindow} onClose={this.onClose}>
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <bold>Title: </bold>
        {this.state.selected.title}
      </div>
      <div>
        <bold>Description: </bold>
        {this.state.selected.description}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  </InfoWindow>)
  : null
}
```

Comment: oh okay it worked, didn't know html tags were react elements too, well the infowindow is not showing up so something else is probably wrong I'll work on that, thanks

Comment: @omcc You can try the info window without the conditional check and some basic dummy data just to check that it does indeed render, then work on the conditional logic. If you found helpful and resolved specific issue feel free to mark resolved/accepted.

Comment: I figured it out just some misnamed variables, thanks though